# Induction on all polynomial runtimes?

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time

Has there ever been a proof technique to show that a language isn't in $\mathrm{P}$, by showing inductively there isn't any $k$ for which the language is in $\mathrm{TIME}(n^k)$?

e.g.: $L\notin \mathrm{TIME}(n^0)$,

$L\notin \mathrm{TIME}(n^k)\rightarrow L\notin \mathrm{TIME}(n^{k+1})$,

$\therefore L\notin \mathrm{P}$.

Is something of the sort feasible? Has it been used?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is used in the definition of creative sets by Joseph and Young (1985). See [the Wikipedia article on polynomial creativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_creativity). But their use is to concoct NP-hard sets with unusual properties (potential counterexamples to the Berman–Hartmanis conjecture rather than to say anything nontrivial about the complexity of any natural algorithmic problem.